# How to use promises to simulate a synchronous for loop

Tags: node.js, while-loop, promise

I cannot get Promises to work (the way I think they should). The following code executes almost immediately.  ie. does not wait the 4 seconds before logging each number to the console.

```
function do_nothing(a) {
    return new Promise(function(accept, reject){
        console.log(a)
        setTimeout(accept(parseInt(a)+1), 4000);
    });
}

function do_til_finish(i) {
    if (parseInt(i) < 5) {
        do_nothing(i)
            .then(j => do_til_finish(j))
            .catch(j =>{})
    } else {
        console.log('All done');    
    }
}
do_til_finish(0);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bollaking/L3fnt3og/4/)

What am I missing?

btw. I do not want to run the loop asynchronously as the statements will use all the memory and freeze the server.

This is not a webserver so I dont need to worry about frustrating users.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a function inside `setTimeout`.

try this:

```
function do_nothing(a) {
  return new Promise(function(accept, reject){
    console.log(a)
    setTimeout(function(){accept(parseInt(a)+1)}, 4000);
  });
}

function do_til_finish(i) {
  if (parseInt(i) < 5) {
    do_nothing(i)
      .then(j => do_til_finish(j))
      .catch(j =>{})
  } else {
    console.log('All done');    
  }
}
console.log("\n");
do_til_finish(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to pass a function to `setTimeout` not to call it.

Second, you need to return a promise from `do_til_finish` to chain further calls.

BTW you don't need to `parseInt`.

```js
function do_nothing(a) {
  return new Promise(function(accept, reject){
    console.log(a)
    setTimeout(accept, 4000, a + 1);
  });
}

function do_til_finish(i) {
  if (i < 5) {
    return do_nothing(i)
      .then(do_til_finish)
      .catch(j =>{})
  } else {
    console.log('All done');    
  }
}
console.log("\n");
do_til_finish(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used the setTimeout function without a callback and passed directly a value, wich is not working as expected. Any way the design is pretty messy I suggest you to look at [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) module for better asynchronous designs patterns.

```
function doNothing(a) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log(a);
    setTimeout(() => resolve(parseInt(a, 10) + 1), 4000);
  });
}

function doUntilFinish(i) {
  if (parseInt(i, 10) < 5) {
    doNothing(i)
      .then(j => doUntilFinish(j))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  } else {
    console.log('All done');
  }
}

doTillFinish(0);
```